# how to update tracking number in interspire shopping cart

Tags: php, interspire-shopping-cart

I am custimizing interspire shopping cart.What do i need to do is to save the tracking number in the system once an order is shipped.
Here is my code

```
$orderID = (int)$_GET['order'];
        $status = (int)$_GET['code'];       

        $command = (string) $_GET['command'];
        $comments =(string) $_GET['comments'];
        $tracking =(string) $_GET['tracking'];
        $carrierData =(string) $_GET['carrier'];


        $update = array(
            'ordstatus' => $status,
            'command'=>$command,
            'comments'=>$comments,
            'tracking'=>$tracking,
            'carrierData'=>$carrierData
        );

        if (!$GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->UpdateQuery('orders', $update, 'orderid = ' . $orderID)) {
            $this->outputError(70, "Order $orderID no longer exists.");
        }
```

So its updating the order status but i need to update the tracking number returned from a thrid party software shipworks.

Any help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: First accept answers to your previous questions please. Nobody will help you if you don't award the people who went trough the trouble of helping you.

Answer (score 0):

In ISC, the tracking number field on the `isc_orders` table is called `ordtrackingno` not `tracking`, so change that in your `$update` array.

You already have the code, just change the field in your array:

```
    $update = array(
        'ordstatus' => $status,
        'ordtrackingno'=>$tracking
    );

    if (!$GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->UpdateQuery('orders', $update, 'orderid = ' . $orderID)) {
```

Comment: Sorry i am newbie can you please post some code samples here?

Answer (score -1):

the free version of Interspire Shopping Cart has the fixed for that.
All known bugs from the latest version of Interspire Shopping Cart 6.1.8 has been
fixed on the free version.

You can download the free version at http://iscexperts.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11

Comment: You must disclose affiliation with external sites. This is simply self promotion.